# Certificate check via OCSP in C#

Tags: c#, certificate, ocsp

I get client ID Card certificate from `Request.ClientCertificate["CERTIFICATE"]` and now I have to check if it's `GOOD`, not `REVOKED` or `UNKNOWN`. I also have a OCSP url.

I checked about library BouncyCastle, but didn't figure out how to use it in my example.

Maybe PHP example can give you an idea:

```
<?php
// User certificate issuer certificate file location
$ocsp_info = Array();

// EID-SK - CA for alternative ID cards until 13.01.2007
$ocsp_info["EID-SK"]["CA_CERT_FILE"]="certs/eid_sk.pem";
// OCSP server adress for this CA
$ocsp_info["EID-SK"]["OCSP_SERVER_URL"]='http://ocsp.sk.ee';
// OCSP responder certificate location for this CA
$ocsp_info["EID-SK"]["OCSP_SERVER_CERT_FILE"]="certs/eid_sk_ocsp.pem";

// EID-SK - CA for alternative ID cards since 13.01.2007
$ocsp_info["EID-SK 2007"]["CA_CERT_FILE"]="certs/eid_sk_2007.pem";
// OCSP server adress for this CA
$ocsp_info["EID-SK 2007"]["OCSP_SERVER_URL"]='http://ocsp.sk.ee';
// OCSP responder certificate location for this CA
$ocsp_info["EID-SK 2007"]["OCSP_SERVER_CERT_FILE"]="certs/EID-SK_2007_OCSP_RESPONDER_2010.pem";

// EID-SK 2011
$ocsp_info["EID-SK 2011"]["CA_CERT_FILE"]="certs/EID-SK_2011.crt";
// OCSP server adress for this CA
$ocsp_info["EID-SK 2011"]["OCSP_SERVER_URL"]='http://ocsp.sk.ee';
// OCSP responder certificate location for this CA
$ocsp_info["EID-SK 2011"]["OCSP_SERVER_CERT_FILE"]="certs/SK_OCSP_RESPONDER_2011.crt";



// ESTEID-SK - CA for Estonian national ID-card certificates issued until 13.01.2007
$ocsp_info["ESTEID-SK"]["CA_CERT_FILE"]="certs/esteid_sk.pem";
$ocsp_info["ESTEID-SK"]["OCSP_SERVER_URL"]='http://ocsp.sk.ee';
$ocsp_info["ESTEID-SK"]["OCSP_SERVER_CERT_FILE"]="certs/ESTEID-SK_OCSP_RESPONDER_2005.pem";

// ESTEID-SK - CA for Estonian national ID-card certificates issued since 13.01.2007
$ocsp_info["ESTEID-SK 2007"]["CA_CERT_FILE"]="certs/esteid_sk_2007.pem";
$ocsp_info["ESTEID-SK 2007"]["OCSP_SERVER_URL"]='http://ocsp.sk.ee';
$ocsp_info["ESTEID-SK 2007"]["OCSP_SERVER_CERT_FILE"]="certs/ESTEID-SK_2007_OCSP_RESPONDER_2010.pem";

// ESTEID-SK - CA for Estonian national ID-card certificates issued since 2011
$ocsp_info["ESTEID-SK 2011"]["CA_CERT_FILE"]="certs/ESTEID-SK_2011.crt";
$ocsp_info["ESTEID-SK 2011"]["OCSP_SERVER_URL"]='http://ocsp.sk.ee';
$ocsp_info["ESTEID-SK 2011"]["OCSP_SERVER_CERT_FILE"]="certs/SK_OCSP_RESPONDER_2011.crt";



// KLASS3-SK - CA for company certificates
$ocsp_info["KLASS3-SK"]["CA_CERT_FILE"]="certs/KLASS3-SK.pem";
$ocsp_info["KLASS3-SK"]["OCSP_SERVER_URL"]='http://ocsp.sk.ee';
$ocsp_info["KLASS3-SK"]["OCSP_SERVER_CERT_FILE"]="certs/KLASS3-SK_OCSP_RESPONDER_2009.pem";

// KLASS3-SK 2010 - CA for company certificates
$ocsp_info["KLASS3-SK 2010"]["CA_CERT_FILE"]="certs/KLASS3-SK_2010.pem";
$ocsp_info["KLASS3-SK 2010"]["OCSP_SERVER_URL"]='http://ocsp.sk.ee';
$ocsp_info["KLASS3-SK 2010"]["OCSP_SERVER_CERT_FILE"]="certs/KLASS3-SK_2010_OCSP_RESPONDER.pem";



// TEST-SK - CA for test certificates
$ocsp_info["TEST-SK"]["CA_CERT_FILE"]="certs/TEST-SK_2009.pem";
$ocsp_info["TEST-SK"]["OCSP_SERVER_URL"]='http://openxades.sk.sise/cgi-bin/ocsp.cgi';
$ocsp_info["TEST-SK"]["OCSP_SERVER_CERT_FILE"]="certs/TEST-SK_OCSP_RESPONDER_2005.pem";

// TEST-SK - CA for test certificates
$ocsp_info["TEST of ESTEID-SK 2011"]["CA_CERT_FILE"]="certs/test_esteid_2011.crt";
$ocsp_info["TEST of ESTEID-SK 2011"]["OCSP_SERVER_URL"]='http://openxades.sk.sise/cgi-bin/ocsp.cgi';
$ocsp_info["TEST of ESTEID-SK 2011"]["OCSP_SERVER_CERT_FILE"]="certs/test_ocsp_2011.crt";



// Openssl binary location
$ocsp_info["OPEN_SSL_BIN"] = '/usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl';

// Temp folder to store certificates
$ocsp_info["OCSP_TEMP_DIR"] = '/var/tmp/';

// When true, then OCSP check will be made
$ocsp_info["OCSP_ENABLED"] = true;


/*
Params:
$cert - user certificate in PEM format

Output:
 0 - OCSP certificate status unknown
 1 - OCSP certificate status valid
 2 - OCSP internal error
 4 - Some error in script
*/

function doOCSPcheck($cert) {

    global $ocsp_info; // Global config array

    $user_good = 0;
    $issuer_dn=$_SERVER["SSL_CLIENT_I_DN_CN"];

    if ($ocsp_info["OCSP_ENABLED"]===false) {
        return Array("OCSP_ENABLED === false", 0);
    }

    // Saving user certificate file to OCSP temp folder
    $tmp_f = fopen($tmp_f_name = tempnam($ocsp_info["OCSP_TEMP_DIR"],'ocsp_check'),'w');
    fwrite($tmp_f,$cert);
    fclose($tmp_f);

    if ($ocsp_info["OCSP_ENABLED"] && isset($ocsp_info[$issuer_dn]["CA_CERT_FILE"]) && isset($ocsp_info[$issuer_dn]["OCSP_SERVER_CERT_FILE"]) && isset($ocsp_info[$issuer_dn]["OCSP_SERVER_URL"])) {


        // Making OCSP request using OpenSSL ocsp command
        $command = $ocsp_info["OPEN_SSL_BIN"].' ocsp -issuer '.$ocsp_info[$issuer_dn]["CA_CERT_FILE"].' -cert '.$tmp_f_name.' -url '.$ocsp_info[$issuer_dn]["OCSP_SERVER_URL"].' -VAfile '.$ocsp_info[$issuer_dn]["OCSP_SERVER_CERT_FILE"];

        $descriptorspec = array(
           0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
           1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
           2 => array("pipe", "w") // stderr is a pipe that the child will write to
        );

        $process = proc_open($command, $descriptorspec, $pipes);

        if (is_resource($process)) {
            fclose($pipes[0]);


            // Getting errors from stderr
            $errorstr="";
            while ($line = fgets($pipes[2])) {
                $errorstr.=$line;
            }

            if ($errorstr!="" && (strpos($errorstr,"Response verify OK")!==0)) {
                $user_good = 4;
            } else {
                // Parsing OpenSSL command stdout
                while ($line = fgets($pipes[1])) {
                    if (strstr($line,'good')) {
                        $user_good = 1;
                    } else if (strstr($line,'internalerror (2)')) {
                        $user_good = 2;
                    }
                }
                fclose($pipes[1]);
            }

            proc_close($process);
        }
    }

    return Array($errorstr, $user_good);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your PHP example is executing openssl in another process to perform the lookup.  Rather than doing this, you may want to go the BouncyCastle route as you indicated.  I've not done this personally (all OCSP I've implemented is handled /w a service that hooks into IIS installed on the server) "Tumbleweed Desktop Validator"  http://www.axway.com/products-solutions/email-identity-security/identity-security/va-suite

A rough example of the BouncyCastle libraries /w c# can be found here, it may be worth a try:

http://bouncy-castle.1462172.n4.nabble.com/c-ocsp-verification-td3160243.html

http://forums.iis.net/t/1100044.aspx <-- you really should only disable the cert check in IIS if you're doing it elsewhere (like via BC libs).